# Inter-line spacing: all but last paragraph line (Word, Office 365)

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

In Microsoft Word (Office 365 desktop version), using inter-line spacing will adjust the space between paragraph lines (quite obviously).

The way it does this depends on the spacing property used: "exact" spacing will add space in a 2:8 ratio above:below the line, and "multiple" spacing will add space exclusively below the line.

My first-world problem here: framed text.

I want to make a framed paragraph, with an equal amount of distance between the frame borders and the text, both above, and below the text.

Here is an example:

Exact line spacing
[image: Exact line spacing]

Multiple line spacing
[image: Multiple line spacing]

Is there a way to overrule this, and apply inter-line spacing to all paragraph lines, while suppressing it for the last line in the paragraph?

Comment: Change the before and after paragraph spacing and don't use exact. See [Change spacing between paragraphs - Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-spacing-between-paragraphs-ee4c7016-7cb8-405e-90a1-6601e657f3ce)